# Plot error_bars with lines in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with the delivery rate of a simulation and its confidence interval. I need to plot an error bar on my chart. Need to be the line graph and also the error bar on a single chart

Sample data:

```
V   D         IC
10 99.2373 0.000200729
30 97.2515 0.00649952
60 94.6761 0.00950475
```

I would like it to look like the example below:

[image: Example]

Here is my code:

```
set nokey
set grid
set key right inside
set xlabel 'Velocidade em Km/h'
set ylabel 'Taxa de Entrega'
set autoscale
set yr[0:100]
set style data lines
plot 'taxa_entrega-AODV-50-250.txt' using 1:2:($2-$3):($2+$3) with yerrorbars
```

Comment: what is your gnuplot code you have tried so far?

Comment: set nokey
        set grid
        set key right inside

        set xlabel 'Velocidade em Km/h'
        set ylabel 'Taxa de Entrega'
        set autoscale
        set yr[0:100]
        set style data lines
        
        
        
        plot 'taxa_entrega-AODV-50-250.txt' using 1:2:($2-$3):($2+$3) with yerrorbars

Answer (score 2):

if you are plotting errorbars you typically plot data `with points` but not necessarily with connected `lines` or `linespoints`. Instead you add a line described by a model or fit.
However, from the image you are referring to I assume you want to have the points nevertheless connected. So, simply add `,\` the same data `''` again as lines.

```
plot 'taxa_entrega-AODV-50-250.txt' using 1:2:($2-$3):($2+$3) with yerrorbars,\
    '' using 1:2 with lines
```

**Addition:** See below what you get with the full code. (I commented out the `set yrange[0:100]` because otherwise one wouldn't see too much with the data you provided. Furthermore, your errobars are in the range of `0.0002 to 0.009`. Relative to the values `94.6 to 99.2`, these will not be bars but more points.

```
reset session
set nokey 
set grid 
set key right inside 
set xlabel 'Velocidade em Km/h' 
set ylabel 'Taxa de Entrega' 
set autoscale 
# set yrange[0:100] 
set style data lines 

plot 'taxa_entrega-AODV-50-250.txt' using 1:2:($2-$3):($2+$3) with yerrorbars,\
    '' using 1:2 with lines
```

[image]

Comment: Right. I would like it to show in the graph the connected error bar. As in the example above. The way you showed me is only one point *

Comment: are you sure that e.g. the error bar of the value 94.6 is 0.009? This will not be a bar but more a point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late, yet I hope someone finds this useful.
Gnuplot actually has something already built-in which is [`errorlines`](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/node141.html).
It connects the center points with a line as asked for.

When using [`errorbars`](https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node140.html) the connected lines are simply omitted. Thus `errorbars` is the counterpart if you want a `points` style, and `errorlines` for the `linespoints` style.